# Changing the Activity which contains Viewpager with Fragments is not possible

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I want to change from a normal activity without a viewpager, tablayout or fragment to an activity which contains tablayout, fragments and viewpager.

Everytime I executed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

My App stops and I can't load.

Update:

Second Activity Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabToolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/century.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );


        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        tabToolbar = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabToolbar);
        tabToolbar.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabToolbar.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.home_button);
        tabToolbar.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.pay_button);
        tabToolbar.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.video_button);
        tabToolbar.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.mipmap.bill_button);

        tabToolbar.getTabAt(tabToolbar.getSelectedTabPosition()).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        tabToolbar.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                tabToolbar.getTabAt(tabToolbar.getSelectedTabPosition()).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tabToolbar.getTabAt(tabToolbar.getSelectedTabPosition()).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#e40079"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
}
```

What can I do to start an activity which containts viewpager with fragments?

Update: LogCat:

```
09-09 14:59:11.002 2650-2650/com.example.fdai3744.t_online20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.fdai3744.t_online20, PID: 2650
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fdai3744.t_online20/com.example.fdai3744.t_online20.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.fdai3744.t_online20.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:41)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: post your second activity code

Comment: So I did. See below my question.

Comment: If your app stops, add the logcat to the question

Comment: Oops its an activity. I thought it was fragment. Posting from mobile

Comment: @cricket_007: See my question again.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` on the second Activity? I assume that layout has no ViewPager

Comment: Ooops, there was a copy mistake. After I corrected this then it finally works! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout XML has ViewPager. Or    ensure your id refers the ViewPager.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: That's not a method of Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cricket_007 for finding the error.
Inside my SetContentView method was "R.layout.activity_main" instead of "R.layout.activity_second".

You can start an Intent to an activity which contains fragments without any problems.